# investigate convergence using comparison test.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Use the comparison test to investigate the convergence/divergence of the series $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$$

So i know that i can change $(\ln n)^{\ln n} = n^{\ln \ln n}.$ But how do i continue from here?

Comment: It's wrong. It's $$e^{\ln(n)\ln\ln(n)}$$

Comment: @FourierTransform They are the same.

Comment: @CaveJohnson My form is more suitable for calculations.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $\ln n^{\ln n}= e^{\ln (\ln n)\cdot \ln n}> e^{2\ln n}=n^2$

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to find $n$ such that $\ln\ln n>1$. Since $\ln\ln x$ is a monotone increasing function, then for $n>e^{e^2}$ we would have $$\frac{1}{(\ln n) ^{\ln n}}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$